# How to solve the dimension problem for SpatialPyramidPooling2D

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I'm currently working with the TensorFlow Addons SpatialPyramidPooling2D layer for image classification and I got the following error when I tried to fit the model.

```
ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 8 and 20 for '{{node MatMul}} = BatchMatMulV2[T=DT_FLOAT, adj_x=false, adj_y=false](feature, transpose_1)' with input shapes: [?,20,8], [8,20,?]
```

I doubt that it's something to do with the output shape of the model. The last layer is supposed to be (None,<number_of_classes>) but I got (None,<number_of_channels>,<number_of_classes>). Because the output of SpatialPyraidPooling2D is a 3D tensor.

I tried to solve it by adding a Flatten layer right after SpatialPyramidPooling2D but it ends up the softmax layer giving me an error as below

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer dense is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 1280 but received input with shape [None, 25600]
```

Comment: What was the shape before the pyramid thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want output of shape `(None, 8)`, I suggest you add a 1D pooling layer after the pyramid pooling thing.

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.random.uniform((10, 20, 8), dtype=tf.float32)

pool = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D()

print(pool(x).shape)
```

```
TensorShape([10, 8])
```